# R - Create new data frame based on variable names

Tags: r

Given two dataframes:

```
    d1=structure(list(y = c(0.04090403771224, 0.321216286364446, -1.00056198338576, 
0.549872767053012, 0.746529361891068, -0.756394989312306, 0.432210041946058, 
1.04202671889042, 0.846691694527378, -0.0372890199537169), x = c(-0.626453810742332, 
0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047, 1.59528080213779, 0.329507771815361, 
-0.820468384118015, 0.487429052428485, 0.738324705129217, 0.575781351653492, 
-0.305388387156356), tx = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), x2 = c(-0.41499456329968, -0.394289953710349, -0.0593133967111857, 
1.10002537198388, 0.763175748457544, -0.164523596253587, -0.253361680136508, 
0.696963375404737, 0.556663198673657, -0.68875569454952)), .Names = c("y", 
"x", "tx", "x2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

d2=dput(reg1.coefs)
structure(c(-0.752515009279226, 2.43055896098665, 0.833724197554561, 
-1.79389056223944), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "x", "tx", "x:tx"
))
```

How can I create a third data frame that selects only the variables in `d2` and creates additional variable(s) corresponding to product of the the variables with a ':' in `d2`. In this example, the code should return a third variable `x:tx` corresponding to the product of `x` and `tx` in `d`.

```
out=structure(list(y = c(0.04090403771224, 0.321216286364446, -1.00056198338576, 
0.549872767053012, 0.746529361891068, -0.756394989312306, 0.432210041946058, 
1.04202671889042, 0.846691694527378, -0.0372890199537169), x = c(-0.626453810742332, 
0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047, 1.59528080213779, 0.329507771815361, 
-0.820468384118015, 0.487429052428485, 0.738324705129217, 0.575781351653492, 
-0.305388387156356), tx = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), x1x2 = c(-0.626453810742332, 0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047, 
1.59528080213779, 0.329507771815361, -0.820468384118015, 0, 0, 
0.575781351653492, -0.305388387156356)), .Names = c("y", "x", 
"tx", "x1x2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is obviously easy for one case, but I need the code to be general enough so that if `d2` contains products of other variables (e.g., `x:x2` or `x:x2:tx`) the correct `out` is produced.

Comment: You might want to back up. Seems like you might be trying to predict values for new observations from a fitted model. The `predict()` function can often take care of this for you.

Comment: You're on the right track, except I want the predictions to come from generated parameter estimates (`d2` in this example) not from the fitted model so `predict()` won't work in this case.

Comment: Then maybe you want something more like `model.matrix`: `model.matrix(reformulate(names(d2)[-1]), d1)` That will give you the columns and the products. You then just need to multiply by the coefficients.

Comment: Sweet! That works pretty well... I'm just a little confused about the intercepts... why does `model.matrix` turn the intercepts to 1 when they are specified in `d2`?

Comment: The column for the intercept in a model matrix for a linear model is always a column of ones.